# pass string to controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to build search field look for users in my system...i will write the name of user in the field and ajax function will pass the name from search field to method in controller this method will return ienumerable of all users those have same name....when i pass id of user it works successfully and i gets the specific user because i pass int value...but The problem occurs when i pass string ...so how to pass the name of user to controller using ajax.

here is view tags

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ResearchAuthor.ApplicationUserId" class="control-label"></label>
        <input id="user"  asp-for="ResearchAuthor.ApplicationUserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicationUserId" />
        <a id="srch" class="btn btn-success">بحث</a>
    </div>
    <select id="add" asp-for="ResearchAuthor.ApplicationUserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicationUserId">
        <option>@Localizer["إختر المستخدم"]</option>
    </select>
```

and ajax code

```
       <script>
    $("#add").empty();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#srch").click(function () {
            $("#add").empty();
            $("#add").append($('<option>', { text: "@Localizer["إختر نوع المقالة"]" }));
            //if ($("#user").val() > 0) {
                var useroptions = {};
            useroptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/ResearchAuthors/GetUsers/";
            useroptions.data = JSON.stringify($("#user").val(););
                useroptions.success =  function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#add").append($('<option>', { value: row.value, text: row.text }))
                    });
                };
                useroptions.error = function () { alert("@Localizer["UniError"]"); };
                $.ajax(useroptions);
            //}
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the function in controller:

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetUsers(string SearchString)
    {
        var users = new SelectList(_context.ApplicationUsers.Where(u=>u.ArName==SearchString), "Id", "ArName");
        return Json(users);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must check it in backend. if it is int then ok but then it is string try to convert into int if is possible.

Comment: but this is not answer...you can add it as comment